# Как определить клавиатуру

Tags: c#, winforms, клавиатура

К компьютеру подключено две клавиатуры. Обе вызывают срабатывание ивента нажатия клавиши. Как определить, с какой именно клавиатуры произошло нажатие?

Comment: Ой-ой... Подозреваю, что тут надо как минимум внедрение функции прослушивания всех нажатий. А то и вообще драйвер какой-то.

Comment: У [WM_KEYDOWN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) в lparam в битах 16-23 может быть что-то интересное.

Comment: `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) { const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100; if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) this.Text = Convert.ToString((int)m.LParam, 2).PadLeft(32, '0'); base.WndProc(ref m); }` - это не работает.

Comment: Чтобы знать, с какого именно устройства пришел ввод, нужно читать этот ввод именно из него, а не из Win API. Либо использовать другие движки ввода типа DirectX, там вроде поддерживается определение устройств ввода, хотя тоже не уверен, нужно изучать, задача странная.